# Bonding 4 Gigabit ethernet and 2 Fiber SFP+

Tags: linux-networking, ethernet, bonding, fiber, lacp

We received a DL380 with 4 Gigabit Ethernet (normal CAT6), and 2 Fiber SFP+ (HPE 10Gb SR SPF+). 
I've successfully managed to bond the 4 Gigabit Ethernet together, and put in place some LACP on our Cisco equipment.

I can succefully bond the 4 Gigabit Ethernet together with the following

```
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
    bond-mode 4
    bond-primary eno1
    bond-slaves eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-downdelay 400
    bond-updelay 800
```

According to [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/358082/are-there-solutions-that-can-combine-gigabit-ethernet-10gig-ethernet-and-fiber) it's impossible to add one of the Fiber channel to the bonding group ?
Sadly, the solution provided is... 404

I'm curious if stuff have changed from now ?
Can we bond 1Gb Ethernet with 10GB SFP+ Fiber ?

Comment: All the links in a group need to be the same speed.

Comment: Also, the hash works best if you have a power of two (2, 4, or 8) number of links in the group.

Comment: Hey Ron - none of this will work if he's trying to bond ethernet and FC - let's see what he's actually got first.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Why would you want all these ports in the same bond group?  Can you tell us more about your real goal?  I suspect you are probably going down a bad path, that is just going to have bad results.

Comment: LAG only works with all ports at the same speed as Ron's pointed out. If you've got aggregate 20 Gbit/s, why care for another 4 Gbit/s? You'll need to use at least two L3 connections (with two LAGs).

Comment: @Zoredache LACP over 5 interface (and even 6 if that's possible), just curious if it's possible to bond 4 1Gb ethernet, and 1 fiber SFP+ 10Gb.

I suppose using that the 4Gbit/s are negligible compare 20Gbit/s with 2 fiber SFP+

It's our storage server with over 30Tb of data on it. Works pretty well with the 4Gbit/s right now, but I'm considering to replace it with some fiber since I received some brand new SFP+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, when you say 'Fibre Channel' do you mean Fibre-Channel or plain old ethernet over fibre? because...they're very different indeed. For a start do your FC SFP+'s actually say 10Gbps? as that's not a valid FC port speed - they go up in 'binary' (1,2,4,8,16,32 etc.) not 'decimal' like Ethernet (1,10,100,1000,10000,100000 etc.) - it'll be printed on the actual SFP+. Also what make/model of 'Fibre-channel' adapter does it have?

Although technically you can do IP-over-FC (I know, I did it once, painful) nobody does, FC and Ethernet are very different protocols and while some switches (Cisco Nexus for one) allow you to plug FC SFP/SFP+'s into their unified ports to allow for downstream conversion to FCoE at no time does the FC port 'talk' Ethernet.

Comment: Apoligize about that. I'm not an english native, and I'm still not 100% sure what if Fiber Channel is the good translation.

Indeed, it's written HPE 10Gb SR SFP+ on it. I guess it's possible, but considering they have different speed, no ?

Comment: That's an Ethernet transceiver (10GBASE-SR), no Fibre Channel. As stated, you can't aggregated interfaces with different speeds. You can aggregate the two 10G SFP+ into one group and the four 1000BASE-T into another.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot @Zac67. I will read more about Fiber channel later today.

Comment: Fibre Channel is a storage/SAN protocol, not entirely but significantly different from Ethernet. It's generally not compatible (although there are compatible variants).

Comment: That’s probably the special cable I received with the server then. It’s a 5m fibre cable (with some black thick protection around), and one SFP on each end (that doesn’t work with my Cisco equipment)